# Tabs in every activity in android

Tags: android

My first page contains 3 tabs. I want to retain all these 3 tabs through out my entire application. That means I want to see these 3 tabs in every view. For example : I have 3 views. First view is Main.class. It contains 3 tabs (Home tab, Favourite tab, settings tab). When I am clicking any one tab (Ex: Home Tab), it shows the contents of Home.class (a ListView) below these tabs. But when I am clicking the ListView view , it will go to another activity(SubListView.class), and I can't see the tabs in that activity. Only contents of that view will be displayed there. How can I show these header tabs in that view also?

Main View: (in Main.class)

```
   final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
   Intent intent; 
   LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, tabHost.getTabContentView(),true); 
   tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Home",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_home)).setContent(new Intent(this, Home.class))); 
   tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Favourites",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_fav)).setContent(new Intent(this, Favourites.class))); 
   tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Settings",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_set)).setContent(new Intent(this, Settings.class))); 
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Home View: (in Home.class)

```
 public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;         
 final ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 ListView listitems=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 
 adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results); 
 listitems.setAdapter(adapter); 
 listitems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
 { 
       //@Override    
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position, long id) 
       {                                                        
               categoryNameFromList=results.get(position); 
               Bundle category_bundle = new Bundle(); 
               category_bundle.putString("selected_item",categoryNameFromList);  
               Intent category_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SubListView.class); 
               category_intent.putExtras(category_bundle); 
               startActivityForResult(category_intent, 1); 

       } 
 });
```

SubList View (in SubListView.class)

```
 TextView txtmessage=new TextView(this); 
 txtmessage.setTex("WELOCME TO SUB LIST VIEW!!"); 
 setContentView(txtmessage);
```

Please help me.. Thanking you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

[Example](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59#more-59) on using TabActivity and Tab widgets.

Comment: I have extended TabActivity in first view(main.class). Can i use TabActivity in every view? or re-create these tabs in every view?

Comment: Nope. Seems you are a little bit confused with the terms of Android. You are going to create an ACTIVITY, which somehow similar to a WINDOW in windows. Now, you are going to put different Views into that ACTIVITY. In this way, the tab bar is persistent across different views.